# Redirection of STDOUT and STDERR not in proper order

Tags: redirect, stdout, command-prompt, stderr

I am typing the following command on windows:

```
C:\> abc.exe -t"param1" >> lofile.txt 2>&1
```

Both STDOUT and STDERR are being redirected to  the output file but there is a problem.

Initially when the program starts there are a 10 lines of STDERR prints and then about 100 lines of STDOUT and then some more lines of STDERR.
 On the console (cmd prompt), the order is correct. But when i redirect to the file using the above command, the order is not correct of the prints.

First STDOUT is printed and then somewhere in between the STDERR prints come.
Why is the sequence not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is as follows:

The buffers for STDOUT and STDERR are separate. 
Once each of the buffers is filled, the contents are copied to the respective file.

Since the STDERR buffer fills after sometimes due to less number of logs, thus, it is moved to the file at a later stage. 
This is why STDOUT logs are seen in the file before STDERR logs even though the program starts with a few lines of STDERR prints.

Comment: This looks like the answer to the OP's question, and should therefore be accepted. I suspect the *real* question though, is what to do about it! :-) I know that's what's bothering me.